# Javascript Switch case statement : fall-through all cases when expression is 'all'

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

How can I implement this behavior in JavaScript Switch Statements

```
expression = 'all' or '1' or '2' 

switch (expression)
{
   case "all" : print case 1 and case 2 
      
   case "1" : print only case 1 

   case "2" print only case 2
}
```

How can I do that? If there's no way to do something like that in JavaScript, I want to know an alternative solution.

Comment: Seems like an `if` would be more useful.

Comment: Yes but I don't want to duplicate code in case 1 and case 2 when all case is true

Comment: Are those cases in a function? You could use a object/array to lookop on the index, or call all the functions on the object if yourinput is 'all'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take two condition instead.

```js
function fn(expression) {
   if (expression === '1' || expression === 'all') console.log(1);
   if (expression === '2' || expression === 'all') console.log(2);
}

fn('1');
console.log('----------');
fn('2');
console.log('----------');
fn('all');
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a 'mapping' object would fit your needs.

Check the key on the object, call that case if needed.

On `all`, loop over `Object.values(obj)` to call all the cases

```js
const mapper = {
  "1": () => console.info('Do case 1'),
  "2": () => console.info('Do case 2')
}

const test = (i) => {
    if (i === 'all') {
        Object.values(mapper).forEach(c => c());
    } else {
        if (mapper[i]) mapper[i]();
        else console.error('No case for', i);
    } 
}

test("1");
test("2");
test("all");
test("9");
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can use the switch statements like this:**

```
expression = 'all'  // "1" or "2"

switch (expression) {
   case "all":
      console.log("1")
      console.log("2")
      break;

   case "1":
      console.log("1");
      break;

   case "2":
      console.log("2");
      break;

   default:
      console.log("Default case");
}
```

Please note that a block will execute until a break statement is encountered. If you do not use the break statement, the execution will fall through. For example, this statement will print 1, 2, and then 1 again because we are not using the break statement in the first case:

expression = 'all'  // "1" or "2"

```
switch (expression) {
   case "all":
      console.log("1");
      console.log("2");

   case "1":
      console.log("1");
      break;

   case "2":
      console.log("2");
      break;

   default:
      console.log("Default case");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can construct your own "switch" kind of

```js
const betterSwitch = value => cases => {
  if (value === 'all') {
    Object.values(cases).forEach(Reflect.apply)
  } else {
    cases[value]()
  }
}

const expression = 'all'
betterSwitch(expression)({
  '1': () => {
    console.log('1')
  },
  '2': () => {
    console.log('2')
  }
})
```

Or you can use a reverse switch trickery

```js
const expression = 'all'

const allOr = v => ['all', v].includes(expression)

switch (true) {
  case allOr('1'):
    console.log('1')
    break
  case allOr('2'):
    console.log('2')
    break
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible to use a switch-case because there is strict logic in how the switch-case works.

You can use a lookup object. When you are using object, you can use `this` to access to other keys.

```
const mapper = {
1: function() { console.log("1")},
2: function() { console.log("2")},
all: function()  {
    this["1"]();
    this["2"]();
}
}

mapper.all();
```

Answer (score -2):

You should read this first: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

```js
let text = "all" // this could be '1' or '2';

switch (text) {
  case '1':
    console.log('print case 1');
    break;
  case '2'
    console.log('print case 2');
    break;
  default:
    console.log('print case 1 and 2');
}
```

This is essentially how you would handle that in Javascript.
Now, if you want types that is another conversation.